# help extracting both contents of a file and values from the same filename using perl

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop, filehandle

Sorry, if this to verbose, but I have a perl script that is partly working. I have a regular expression that extracts either `foo|bar` and a prefix on a string given. But the problem is my strings are also FILE NAMES which I also want to open and retrieve its contents like `locale_col.dat.2010120813.png` (see Expected Output below).

The output now looks like this:

```
Content:/home/myhome/col/.my_file_del.mail@locale.foo.org
Key1:foo:Key2:col
Content:/home/myhome/col/.my_file_del.dp1.bar.net
Key1:bar:Key2:col
Content:/home/myhome/jab/.my_file_del.mail@locale.foo.org
Key1:foo:Key2:jab
Content:/home/myhome/jab/.my_file_del.dp1.bar.net
Key1:bar:Key2:jab
```

I need help tweaking this so that in one pass I can read the list of strings (file names from FileList.txt), extract particular values from the file name path (using regex) and open the file name for its contents. I hope that makes sense or am I looking at breaking this into 2 perl scripts? Thanks for your input.

Code (WIP):

```
open FILE, "< /home/myname/FileList.txt";
while (<FILE>) {
 my $line = $_;
   chomp($line);
      print "Content:$_"; #This is just printing the filenames. 
                #I want to get the contents of those file names instead. Stuck here.
      if ($line =~ m/home\/myname\/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.].*/){
         print "Key1:$2:Key2:$1\n";
      }
}
close FILE;
```

Contents of FileList.txt:

```
/home/myname/col/.my_file_del.mail@locale.foo.org
/home/myname/col/.my_file_del.dp1.bar.net
/home/myname/jab/.my_file_del.mail@locale.foo.org
/home/myname/jab/.my_file_del.dp1.bar.net
```

Example content of one of the listed files: (which I need help here with to extract)

```
$ cat .my_file_del.mail@locale.foo.org 
locale_col.dat.2010120813.png
```

Expected Output:

```
Content:locale_col.dat.2010120813.png
Key1:foo:Key2:col
...
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ALWAYS these 2 lines !!!
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/home/myname/FileList.txt';
# use 3 args open and test openning for failure
open my $FILE, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    print "Content:$line\n"; #This is just printing the filenames. 
    #I want to get the contents of those file names instead. Stuck here.
    if ($line =~ m#home/myname/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.].*#) {
        open my $file2, '<', $line or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
        while(my line2 = <$file2>) {
          print $line2;
        }
        close $file2;
        print "Key1:$2:Key2:$1\n";
    }
}
close $FILE;
```

Comment: @goreSplatter: Thank you, it's really a best practice!!

Comment: @bourbaki - thanks. i am trying this, although i'm erroring with using "FILE" file handle. does my $FILE have to be declared?

Comment: I've made a mistake in the line `while (my $line = <FILE>) {` that should be `while (my $line = <$FILE>) {`. I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the filenames, why not open those?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', '/home/myname/FileList.txt';
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    say "Key1:$2:Key2:$1" if m!home/myname/(\w{3})[^.]*[.](\w+)[.].*!;
    next unless -e $line; #We skip to the next line unless the file exists
    open my $inner_fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$inner_fh>) {
        say;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks like I just needed to open another fh within my while loop. ok, i've never used 'say'. will need to look this up.

Comment: say is just print with an automatic \n at the end. Extra laziness, is all. Also, although I'm using autodie to get the same effect here, you should really consider checking the return value of all your system calls (such as open), like in bourbaki's answer, as well as using the three-argument form of open (for more info on that, see perlopentut in perldoc, and this: http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2005-11-17.html)